# выравнивание блоков display block

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавления display: flex почему то два блока на одном уровне, а первый нет. Мне нужно, чтобы они симметрично выравнились по низу. Я делал align-items: end, но всеравно так же два блока ниже первого, как это исправить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

класс .info это и есть эти блоки

вот видно, как первый блок не прижимается к низу

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу ваш код

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `align-items: flex-end`

Comment: я ж говорил я делала так всеравно неполучается два блока ниже первого

Comment: я не экстрасенс, я ваш код не видел, я лишь могу предположить что вы совершили ошибку в записи  align-items: end, где не хватает flex-. Могу лишь ещё одно предположение сделать, что в первом блоке большой line-height и поэтому выглядит так не ровно

Comment: margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; так?